VSCode keeps telling me I have commits to push to a repository that doesn't exist
I think I accidently connected a repository to my main users folder. I ended up deleting the repository on GitHub, however every time I open a new window in VSCode and it is not working in a specific repository it says I have over 10,000 changes in my Source Control with this warning "The git repository at "c:*******" (blocked out the path for privacy) has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled." I tried running git remote rm origin in the directory where it says the repository is but nothing changes. Then I tried removing through VSCode's UI of Removing Remote and it says "Your repository has no remotes." What have I done wrong and how do I fix it?

You have succesfully removed the link to the (non existing) remote repository, you have nothing more to do on that front.
The message about 10k modifications is about your local repository only: in its current state, your local repository has a lot (over 10k) of individual files that are modified or untracked, and VSCode tells you "I can't handle that".

Some possible causes:

you have a directory which should be in your .gitignore (node_modules/ ? build/ ?)
many files have been modified, because of a formatter, or line ending modifications, or ...

Run git status in a terminal to have a view of what is shown as "modified" and "untracked", and act accordingly.
